# How to make AngularStrap typeahead selection uneditable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I'm using AngularStrap's typeahead element:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedFruit" bs-options="fruit for fruit in fruits" placeholder="Begin typing fruit" bs-typeahead>
```

When a fruit is selected in the typeahead it is displayed in the typeahead as a string that can be edited by the user. I want the user to only be able to submit the fruit by its exact name. If a user chooses `apple` and then by accident edits the string to be `aple` my app will crash when they submit.

Is there a way to make the string uneditable in the typeahead once it is selected? The user should be able to change their selection by choosing another fruit from the typeahead array, so the first selection shouldn't be unchangeable.

Comment: Would adding validation to the form to check if it is a valid fruit be a possible solution, or is that not enough in this particular use case?

Comment: Good idea, but I would rather solve the problem by making the strings uneditable. I think it would be one less thing that could potentially annoy the user.

Comment: Makes sense. You can definitely make it uneditable... The trick here is making it uneditable, but still allowing someone to pick a new option from the type ahead (because they need to edit it in order to do that). It could track the last valid value and switch back to that if the current value is invalid? Would that work?

Comment: Ahh yes, good idea. I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, going off of Luke's suggestion above, the following solution is what worked for me:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="pie in pies">
    <input type="text" bs-on-select="addSpelling" ng-blur="spellCheck()" bs-options="stock for stock in allBaskets" ng-model="pie.fruit" bs-typeahead>
</div>
```

Note it needs to be `bs-on-select="addSpelling"` and not `bs-on-select="addSpelling()"` since the second option will cause the function to be fired when the page loads.

In controller:

```
$scope.addSpelling = function(){
    this.scope.spelling = this.scope.$modelValue;
}

$scope.spellCheck = function(){
    if(this.pie.fruit == ""{
        return;
    }
    if(this.pie.fruit != this.spelling){
        this.pie.fruit = this.spelling;
    }    
}
```